# Gnuplot: plot data from command

Tags: gnuplot

I know I can plot with data from `stdin` by using `'-'` as the data source, but is there any way I can plot data output from a command the same way? I.e., instead of running the command and piping to the gnuplot script, can I specify the command in the gnuplot script itself?

Something like this (but this doesn't work):

```bsh
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'test.png'

cmd = "`./mycmd`" # running ./mycmd in terminal gives my data to stdout.
                  # the command can be several other commands, piped together.
                  # i'm only interested in whatever comes to stdout after running
                  # the entire thing.

plot cmd u 2:3 w lines # etc...
```

The above makes `cmd` contain a single long line with all the lines of output smashed together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
plot '< ./mycmd'
```

Comment: Brilliant! It's always easier than you think =)

Comment: @TomasLycken: It should work. Maybe there is something wrong on line 1 of your data (a header)?

Comment: I tried again with redirecting and plotting from the file, and for some reason it doesn't work now - that's why I deleted my comment. Will investigate further...

Comment: The problem was unrelated - and silly. I had written my plot command as `plot thecommand \' followed by a newline and a few different commands. I commented out the first of these, but gnuplot can't handle an escaped line-break with comments between the lines. Thanks!